# UITest compare value of element in expectation

Tags: swift, xctest, uitest

I am currently trying to figure out when an activity indicator is on or off. I realised that, when on, its `value` is 1, 0 when off.

I am trying to check if that `value` is 1 or 0 like this:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "value == 0")
let expectation = expectation(
        for: predicate, 
        evaluatedWith: app.activityIndicators["activityId"],
        handler: nil)

if XCTWaiter().wait(for:[expectation], timeout: 20) == .completed {
    print ("Activity indicator is off")
} else {
    print ("Activity indicator is on")
}
```

The **current problem** is that the timeout is always reached. Whenever I set a breakpoint at the `if` and type this in the console:

```
po app.activityIndicators["activityId"].value
```

The result is:

```
Optional<Any>
- some : 0
```

However, after I let the test run again, the timeout is reached and the else branch is taken.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong while accessing the `value` of the `element` in the expectation?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you ever launch your app? Is this the only UI Test you've written, or do you have others that work?

Comment: Around 3 million people launch this app daily and there are about 20 other UI tests that work. So far we were working around the activity indicator by just waiting, but I want to make something more elegant. Why are this questions relevant, if I may ask?

Comment: I meant in the test, do you ever call `app.launch()` before interacting with the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've both **launched your app** and **set the accessibility identifier** of your activity indicator correctly (which it seems you've done), the reason your code doesn't work is that `value` is a *string, not an integer*.

Replacing your predicate with the following will make your code work:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "value == \"0\"")
```